# Difference between Using Java Cookies and Using Database

Tags: database, cookies, web-applications, persistent

I am new to web Application development. I have a task of making a JSP persistent. What are the methods to do so? Do I need to Write cookies or created a database to continuously fetch data from Webpage. What are the advantages of one over another.

Any kind of tutorial or resources will be helpful. I am using Eclipse as a development tool. I have deployed the app on AWS, [HERE](http://myfirstelasticbeans-envhelloworld.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/)

Comment: Way too broad for SO (and asking for tutorials is completely off-topic). You may want to think what type of and amount of persistence you need (i.e. cookies are very limited in size/lifetime compared to DB or event JavaScript local storage).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Is there any limit on how much a cookie can store?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I got my answer.Thanks a lot for your help. I think I should use cookies.